# AWS Elastic Beanstalk, wont update django.config with "eb deploy"

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, cors, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've deployed a API application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk written in python and django. I'm now developing the frontend from which I'm trying to send a simple get request to the AWS python server. Trying different solutions to the CORS header issue I added:

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/cors.conf" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      <Location "/">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Authorization, Content-Type, Accept"
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
      </Location>
```

to the django.config file which made it work on AWS but not locally (the django.config file is located in .ebextensions file). I decided to instead use the 'django-cors-headers' middleware so that it would work both locally and on AWS. But now it wont work on AWS since it registers multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin domains.

So after removing the above files: code from django.config the problem persisted so the reasonable problem would be that the header is added both by the middleware and by the django.config code which I'm not able to remove.

Could someone help me find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, to fix it, you need to add this on your django.config:

```
container_commands:
  01_wsgipass:
    command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'
```

Comment: I still get the: 

The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Even after adding the code.

Comment: I downloaded the latest code from AWS and found that the django.config in fact had updated to the code with the headers but when sending a request with postman i get the exact headers configured preciously in the django.config file.... Super wierd